# cp command conflicts on non-existent files

Tags: linux, command-line, cp

An error occurs when I ran this command on a RedHat server where `data` was a directory:

```
rm -rf data; cp -r another_dir data
```

An error occurs with this command:

```
cp: cannot create directory `data/test': File exists
```

This error does not always happen. Usually when I see this error I can simply rerun the commands and it would succeed. Also, changing the `;` sign to a `$` does not solve this problem.

I simply don't understand. How could this even be possible?

Answer (score 1):

What is data? A directory or a file ?
If that is a directory try `rmdir data`
If it is a file , try `rm -f data`

Since `rm -rf data;cp -r another_dir data` is two different commands . So just try one by one and give me the result

Comment: As I stated in the question, `data` is a directory. `rm -r` should be the same as `rmdir`. The problem is that, I've already removed the directory in the previous command, how could there be a conflict?

Comment: If it is a directory , then you should rmdir

Comment: `rmdir` is only for empty directories. `rm -rf` works with non-empty directories also. I am sure that after `rm -rf`, the directory is removed. This error could also occur when I run these two commands one by one. As I said, it did not always happen.